# Does a specific blood group enhance the Plasmodium growth?

Tags: cell-culture, infection, parasitology, pathogenesis

I am maintaining *Plasmodium falciparum* cultures for past 6 months. For the blood culture, usually we lab members take turns  and donate blood for the culture. I observed that the parasite's normal growth cycle were fast and more healthy in B+ blood, little slow in AB+ blood. But on the whole the culture was maintained good but I really observed fast stage transitions in B+.

Is this really possible? Does a specific blood group have an impact on *Plasmodium* growth? Did anyone notice the same issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well documented observation that *Plasmodium* (*vivax* and *knowlesi*) infection is dependent on the Duffy blood groups <sup>[[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2271/)]</sup>.

Individuals lacking the Duffy antigens (Fy<sup>a</sup> and Fy<sup>b</sup>) have lower susceptibility to malaria. Plasmodium expressed Duffy Binding Proteins facilitate in establishing the initial contact between the merozoite and the RBCs.

However, *Plasmodium* has evolved to break this dependence on Duffy antigens <sup>[[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0912496107), [3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pntd.0001192)]</sup>.

For, the ABO blood group system, it has been observed that the blood group-O is associated with lower severity of *P.falciparum* malaria in adults  <sup>[[4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1182/blood-2007-03-077602), [5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0705390104)]</sup>, which possibly happens because of reduced rosetting (binding of infected RBCs with uninfected RBCs) <sup>[[5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0705390104)]</sup>.

---

**References:**

1. Dean L. Blood Groups and Red Cell Antigens [Internet]. Bethesda (MD): National Center for Biotechnology Information (US); 2005. Chapter 9, The Duffy blood group. Available from: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2271/
2. Ménard, Didier, et al. "[Plasmodium vivax clinical malaria is commonly observed in Duffy-negative Malagasy people.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0912496107)" *Proc Nat Acad Sci, USA* 107.13 (2010): 5967-5971.
3. Mendes, Cristina, et al. "[Duffy negative antigen is no longer a barrier to Plasmodium vivax–molecular evidences from the African West Coast (Angola and Equatorial Guinea).](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pntd.0001192)" *PLoS Negl Trop Dis* 5.6 (2011): e1192.
4. Cserti, Christine M., and Walter H. Dzik. "[The ABO blood group system and Plasmodium falciparum malaria.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1182/blood-2007-03-077602)" *Blood* 110.7 (2007): 2250-2258.
5. Rowe, J. Alexandra, et al. "[Blood group O protects against severe Plasmodium falciparum malaria through the mechanism of reduced rosetting.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0705390104)" *Proc Nat Acad Sci, USA* 104.44 (2007): 17471-17476.